# Loading first 100 rows of excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a very large excel file and I'd like to only load the first 100 rows. It seems that pandas doesn't do this well, as it takes about 10 seconds to load in the following command:

```
pd.read_excel('excel/BigFile.xlsx', nrows=100)
```

It seems to take the same amount of time as not even passing in the `nrows` param at all. Is there a way to "quickly" read the first 100 rows of an excel file? If not in pandas, are there other tools that can do this better?

Comment: The extended time might be the “import pandas as pd” line. It takes 4-5 seconds on my PC as well. It’s a huge library. Try the xlrd module or even the csv module (and save as a csv - knowing you’ll lose some features) if 10 seconds is too long.

Comment: As a response to the comment above by @NickDima, in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) it says you can use the xlrd engine to read the files.

Comment: @mariogarcc the problem still remains if you have to import pandas at all

Comment: @NickDima I'm sorry, why is importing pandas a problem? I'm just saying that instead of importing some other module you can try the xlrd engine that pandas has to offer. If it solves the problem, good; if it doesn't, we can search for other solutions.

Comment: It takes time to import a module, and pandas is a fairly large module. Shouldn't make too much of a difference though, importing pandas takes less than a second on my laptop and is essentially instant on my PC.

Comment: @NickDima importing pandas has nothing to do with it. I just mean loading the excel file after pandas is loaded.

Comment: @DavidL Ah, my apologies. I made an assumption that it took 10seconds to run the entire python script, including imports. If it’s 10seconds for just the command pd.read_excel() then ignore my commentary!

Comment: @DavidL If it's just plain textual data, try saving as a CSV. CSV reading tends to be faster than Excel spreadsheet reading.

Comment: @DavidL is converting it to a `pkl` file an option?

Comment: @Chris -- sure, how would that be done? Wouldn't I first need to load the entire python file into memory though?

Comment: @DavidL you would need to load the file into memory first, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Cause

`pandas` uses the [`xlrd`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package under the hood for reading out excel files. The default behaviour of `xlrd` seems to be to load the entire excel workbook into memory, regardless of what data is read out in the end. This would explain why you're noticing no reduction in loading time when you're using the `nrows` parameter of [`pd.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

`xlrd` does offer the possibility to [load worksheets on demand](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/on_demand.html) instead, but that won't be of much help unfortunately if all your data is in one single very large excel worksheet (plus it seems that this option doesn't support `.xlsx` files).

### Solution

The excel parsing package [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io) does offer the possibility to [load individual excel rows on demand](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html) (i.e. only the needed excel rows are loaded into memory). With a little bit of custom code, `openpyxl` can be harnessed to retrieve your excel data as a pandas dataframe:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd


def read_excel(filename, nrows):
    """Read out a subset of rows from the first worksheet of an excel workbook.

    This function will not load more excel rows than necessary into memory, and is 
    therefore well suited for very large excel files.

    Parameters
    ----------
    filename : str or file-like object
        Path to excel file.
    nrows : int
        Number of rows to parse (starting at the top).

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        Column labels are constructed from the first row of the excel worksheet.

    """
    # Parameter `read_only=True` leads to excel rows only being loaded as-needed
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filename, read_only=True, data_only=True)
    first_sheet = book.worksheets[0]
    rows_generator = first_sheet.values

    header_row = next(rows_generator)
    data_rows = [row for (_, row) in zip(range(nrows - 1), rows_generator)]
    return pd.DataFrame(data_rows, columns=header_row)


# USAGE EXAMPLE
dframe = read_excel('very_large_workbook.xlsx', nrows=100)
```

Using this code to load the first 100 rows of a >100MB single-sheet excel workbook takes just <1sec on my machine, whereas doing the same with `pd.read_excel(nrows=100)` takes >2min.

### Edit

The `pandas.read_excel()` method in pandas version 1.2.0 and higher no longer uses the `xlrd` package for reading of .xlsx files, but instead uses `openpyxl`. The solution remains valid though.

Comment: this is awesome, thanks for the suggestion. This is the route we ended up going. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `on_demand` option in xlrd isn't supported for .xlsx files.

Answer (score 3):

The [**sxl**](https://pypi.org/project/sxl/) module was created expressly for this purpose. To get the first 100 rows of a worksheet:

```
import sxl

wb = sxl.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets[1]  # this gets the first sheet
data = ws.head(100)
```

Comment: thanks, I'll check this out. I thought `openpyxl` worked great though. Do you have any experience in using sxl vs openpyxl?

Comment: I have relatively little experience with either one, actually. I almost always use xlrd. I like its API the best, and it seems the most efficient if you *do* need to load all the data, which I almost always do. The advantage of sxl is that it is very small, with a simple API. So it's easy to use, easy to understand, and easy to tweak if necessary. The advantage of openpyxl is that it is full-featured and well established, and can do both reading and writing. (I use the combination of xlrd and XlsxWriter instead of openpyxl.)